# string-set CSS property is not recognized by browser

Tags: html, css

I am working on a html to PDF project. I am following the solution from an [older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322647/re-displaying-the-current-heading-after-a-page-break), but got stuck on the first step which is:

```
h1 {
    string-set: doctitle content();
}

@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 1.6cm .6cm 1.2cm .6cm;

    @top-center {
        content: string(doctitle);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting a "Unknown property name" on the Dev tools.

Tried on: Chrome version 81.0.4044.129 & Firefox 75.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764700/using-css-string-set-property-and-content-method

Comment: I don't think `set-string` is a valid CSS prop, do you need to add a pre-processor tag of some sort?

Comment: I don't think that's my problem. My problem is that `string-set` is not recognized by the browser.

Comment: Pulled [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#setting-named-strings-the-string-set-pro) form W3, so it should be a CSS prop? Unless it has been deprecated somewhere along the lines, but I'm not sure where to look for that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after researching a ton more, I think I have the answers. `string-set` is an actual  CSS property in [W3's CSS Page Media Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/) but like the OP in [Has the paged media module been abandoned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079561/has-the-paged-media-module-been-abandoned), there does not seem to be a full adoption in browsers for paged media module specs even though caniuse says it's fully supported.

The reason it works in [Re-displaying the current heading after a page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322647/re-displaying-the-current-heading-after-a-page-break) is because the OP uses WeasyPrint, which does not rely on the browser's CSS rendering to create the PDF.

The takeaway is that in 2020, HTML to PDF is still a massive pain because of fragmented adoption of W3's specs. The same HTML file will look different in the browser's print preview, WKHTMLTOPDF and WeasyPrint.

Some of the reading that helped me finally solve this:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/